# How to get actually allocated tablespace sizes?

Tags: postgresql, storage, database-size

A Postgres tablespace is cluster-wide.
Therefore, how do I calculate how much space is allocated by each database in Postgres tablespaces?

Answer (score 20):

To get the disk space occupied by a database (nicely formatted):

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('mydb'));
```

Disk space occupied by a tablespace:

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_tablespace_size('mytblspace'));
```

Find out more about [database object size functions in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE):

Comment: One could very usefully combine this with a `SELECT` on the system tables: `SELECT spcname, pg_size_pretty(pg_tablespace_size(spcname)) FROM pg_tablespace;` and `SELECT datname, pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(datname)) FROM pg_database;`.